# TypeError: must be str, not int

Tags: python

```
print ('welcome, uhhh whats your name?')
name = str(input('tell me here:    '))
print ('thats better')
import time
print ('welcome,',name,'this is the forst step on your long journey...')
time.sleep(0.5)
print ('well no, this is just a widget app...')
time.sleep(0.5)
print ('so umm just enter the widget you want')
print (' by the way this will repeat forever sooo, just kill the program when you have had enough')
while True:
    wid = str(input('choose from these(CAPS SENSITIVE): dice, usernamegen,   '))
    import random
    if wid == 'dice':
        print ('YOU HAVE CHOSEN...')
        print ('DICE!')
        dice = int(input('how many would you like to roll(MAX3):   '))
        if dice == 1:
            print ('you rolled a',(random.randint(1,6)))
        elif dice == 2:
            print ('you rolled a',(random.randint(1,6)))
            print ('you rolled a',(random.randint(1,6)))
        elif dice == 3:
            print ('you rolled a',(random.randint(1,6)))
            print ('you rolled a',(random.randint(1,6)))
            print ('you rolled a',(random.randint(1,6)))
        else:
            print ('next time enter an option')
    elif wid == 'usernamegen':
        print ('This app will generate your online username')
        lname = input('enter your last name here    ')
        print('wait 3 seconds')
        username = name[:1]+lname[:3]+random.randint(1,99999)
        time.sleep(3)
        print (username)
```

this was the code that I used but I got this error

```
  line 33, in <module>
    username = str(name[:1]+lname[:3]+random.randint(1,99999))
TypeError: must be str, not int
```

Comment: The error message says it all. You can only add up a single type. So either `name[:1]`, `lname[:3]`, `random.randint(1,99999)` must be strings, or all of em must be ints.

Comment: `random.randint` return an `int` you should use `str(random.randint)` in order to convert that to `str`.

Answer (score 2):

```
name[:1]+lname[:3]+str(random.randint(1,99999))
```

Use it as mentioned above. This should work.